# WSO2 Identity Server With SCIM 2.0 and Active Directory User Creation Error

Tags: wso2

I have a Identity Server version 5.3.0 installed on my server and activated SCIM 2.0 user provisioning based on the documentation provided. Active directory is set as the primary user store here. The identity server created the admin user and group successfully in the Active Directory without any errors, however, my problem is when I want to create more users via the UI of Identity server I get this error:

[LDAP: error code 16 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C091027, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839 ]; remaining name 'cn=*****'

And when Trying to create the user with SCIM 2.0 with curl I get the this error:

{"schemas":"urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error","detail":"Error in adding the user: *** to the user store. Error while adding the user to the Active Directory for user : ***","status":"500"}

My claims are set as follows:

Claims for urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0--->

```
    urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:meta.resourceType 
    urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:meta.lastModified 
    urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:meta.created 
    urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:meta.location 
    urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:id 
    urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:userName
```

This is configured based on the https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS410/SCIM+User+Provisioning+With+IS+Having+Active+Directory+User+Store

I just applied it to the urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0 and not the urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0  because this is SCIM 2.0 Version and not version 1.0

P.S . I am using Active Directory within Server 2016 with ldapS.

Does anybody have any any ideas about what causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

According to [1] **[LDAP: error code 16 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C091027, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839]** - Indicates that one of the attributes you are passing in the user create operation does not exist in the entry. Please recheck all the attributes you have mapped in the attribute map look up.

[1]https://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=LDAP_Error_Codes

Comment: I am just passing user name and password attributes and nothing more. This error happens in the User Interface of the Identity Server User creation too.

Comment: Please check whether claim mapping is properly configured against the AD attributes for SCIM claims. Refer http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm to find the list of supported attributes in Active Directory. In the claim mappings for SCIM claims you need to add valid and existing mapped attributes in AD.

Comment: I have added the correct attributes. simple ones. For scim1 there is a guide on configuring attributes for inbound user provisioning: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Configuring+Active+Directory+User+Stores+for+Inbound+Provisioning . setting this will make scim version 1 works correctly with active directory and users can be added via scim 1. but there is no guide for scim 2 on this. could you help if I provide you with my server details?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set up **Last Modified Time** claim in WSO2 claim dialect. I have set it to use Directory String type attribute in Active Directory.